# Is the spanning tree found by the algorithm DFS always show in preorder?

Tags: c++, recursion, depth-first-search, backtracking, modified-preorder-tree-t

I'm doing an implementation of the DFS algorithm in c + + to find a spanning tree, the output for a spanning tree using the algorithm DFS is always preorder or is it pure coincidence?.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DFS is by definition preorder if you print them as you enter them.

> A preordering is a list of the vertices in the order that they were
>   first visited by the depth-first search algorithm.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search

Comment: Thanks a lot, I suspected from the start, excuse my english.